# fileinput.input() function giving unexpected output

Tags: python

I am using this script to remove repeated lines and the values greater than 10000.

```
import fileinput
import os, sys
import re

def get_immediate_subdirectories(a_dir):
   return [name for name in os.listdir(a_dir) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(a_dir,name))]

for i in get_immediate_subdirectories(os.getcwd()+'\population_vs_time\\'):
  for j in get_immediate_subdirectories(os.getcwd()+'\population_vs_time\\'+i):        
    for file in os.listdir(os.getcwd()+'\population_vs_time\\'+i+'\\'+j):
        seen=set()
        my_dir=os.getcwd()+'\population_vs_time\\'+str(i)+'\\'+str(j)+'\\'+file
        matches=re.match("time",str(file))
        if not matches:
            print (my_dir)
            f = fileinput.input(files=my_dir)

            for line in f:
                if line in seen: continue  # skip duplicate
                flag=0
                words = line.split()
                for word in words:
                    # try:
                    i=float(word)
                    if i>10000:
                        flag=1
                        break
                    # except ValueError:
                    #     flag=1
                if flag==1: continue
                seen.add(line)
                print line, # standard output is now redirected to the file

            f.close()
```

I have my_dir variable of type string, using print function to show the value of this variable gives proper output as expected for first three files

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Guimoo\bin\population_vs_time\mocmaes\frontsize_gen=220\mocmaes_gen_220_100_.csv
C:\Program Files (x86)\Guimoo\bin\population_vs_time\mocmaes\frontsize_gen=220\mocmaes_gen_220_120_.csv
C:\Program Files (x86)\Guimoo\bin\population_vs_time\mocmaes\frontsize_gen=220\mocmaes_gen_220_140_.csv
```

but when next file is read it gives random number as output (1.70512 instead of mocmaes)

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Guimoo\bin\population_vs_time\1.70512\frontsize_gen=220\mocmaes_gen_220_160_.csv
```

I think I am missing basics of python \ escape character. Is it so?

Note: The screenshot of mocmaes folder is attached [image]

Comment: Please post the actual code.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that this file exists?

Comment: Are you sure you are referring to the correct folder? Your first line has `\population_vs_time\mocmaes\frontsize_gen=220\`and your second line has `\\population_vs_time\\1.6719\\frontsize_gen=220\\`

Comment: You're escaping your p characters here: '\population_vs_time\\'

Comment: i am also puzzeled by that output because same variable is used as input for print as well as fileinput function

Comment: @Mike print gives me proper output it does not escape p

Comment: I misinterpreted my error

Comment: Whatever the error in your case may be. Use `os.path.join`